# Fill triangle code displaying at the wrong coordinates

Tags: rust, graphics, webassembly

I've been trying to get the following code to work for my Disp implementation. I've successfully written a draw_line and draw_triangle function, but I cannot figure out why my fill_triangle function is causing issues.

My implementation is based on the following tutorial found [here](https://gabrielgambetta.com/computer-graphics-from-scratch/07-filled-triangles.html).

The code base is quite large so I can add more snippets as requested.

```rust
pub fn fill_triangle(&mut self, mut x1: f32, mut y1: f32, mut x2: f32, mut y2: f32, mut x3: f32, mut y3:f32, c: Colour){
    if y1 == y2 && y2 == y3 {
        return;
    }
    // Sort vertices by y-coordinate (top to bottom)
    if y1 > y2 {
        std::mem::swap(&mut x1, &mut x2);
        std::mem::swap(&mut y1, &mut y2);
    }
    if y1 > y3 {
        std::mem::swap(&mut x1, &mut x3);
        std::mem::swap(&mut y1, &mut y3);
    }
    if y2 > y3 {
        std::mem::swap(&mut x2, &mut x3);
        std::mem::swap(&mut y2, &mut y3);
    }

    // Calculate slopes
    let slope1 = (x3 - x1) / (y3 - y1);
    let slope2 = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
    let slope3 = (x3 - x2) / (y3 - y2);

    // Initialize current x coordinates
    let mut curr_x1 = x1;
    let mut curr_x2 = x1;

    // Scanline filling
    for y in y1 as usize..=y3 as usize {
        let start_x = (curr_x1 + (y - y1 as usize) as f32 * slope1).max(0.0).min(self.width as f32 - 1.0) as usize;
        let end_x = (curr_x2 + (y - y1 as usize) as f32 * slope2).max(0.0).min(self.width as f32 - 1.0) as usize;

        for x in start_x..=end_x {
            self.set_pixel(x, y, c.clone());
        }

        curr_x1 += slope1;
        curr_x2 += slope2;

        if y == y2 as usize {
            curr_x1 = x2;
            curr_x2 += slope3;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of my draw_triangle function working:
[image: draw triangles cube]

Here are a few pictures of the fill triangle function not working:
[image: fill triangle 1]
[image: fill triangle 2]
[image: fill triangle 3]